# Publishing an Open Graph story with an image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I am publishing a "Run a course" story with JavaScript like this :

```
var obj = {
            "fb:app_id": "myappid",
            "og:type": "fitness.course",
            "og:url": "",
            "og:title": "",
            "og:image": ""
};

FB.api('/me/fitness.runs', 'post', {course : obj, image : imgURL},
```

I want to attach an image to this story.The image is supposed to be added to user's photos too.  But I don't know how to do that, I searched through web but I couldn't come up with anything. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the image parameter as a array contains hash like below.

```
images[0]['url'] = imgURL
images[0]['user_generated'] = 'true'

FB.api('/me/fitness.runs', 'post', {course : obj, image : images},
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had more success by posting User Generated Photos like this

```
'image[0][url]' = imgURL
'image[0][user_generated]' = true
```